# Why are stars portrayed to have pointed corners even when they emit light in every direction

Tags: astronomy, diffraction, stars

Is it just for representative purpose or does it have any meaning

[image: Here , as in this image, 6 corners(sometimes 4) are shown in this picture of a distant star ,]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike

Comment: and notably not just telescope support arm diffraction but also eyelash and eyelid diffraction, since such spikes were also featured in artwork that predates the telescope